# Porque me salta un error al tratar de mostrar los datos de un array en php

Tags: php, mysql, array

Recién estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación, estoy teniendo un problema al tratar de mostrar el nombre de la persona que inicio sesión en mi pagina `PHP`.

Al usar `print_r($_SESSION)` me muestra:

> "Array ( [usuario] => Array ( [id] => 1 [nombre] => Walter [apellido] => Suarez [user] => Walter2306 [email] => walter2306@gmail.com [password] => 123456789 ) )"

Al tratar de usar `['user']` me salta error:

> "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\abbaphp-bt52.0\administrador\Template\sidebar.php on line 18
> Array"

```php
<?php
require './config/database.php';
$db = new Database();
$con = $db->conectar();
if (isset($_POST["btnLogin"])) {
    $txtEmail = ($_POST['txtEmail']);
    $txtPassword = ($_POST['txtPassword']);

    $adminSQL = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE email=:email AND password=:password");
    $adminSQL->bindParam("email", $txtEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $adminSQL->bindParam("password", $txtPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $adminSQL->execute();

    $registro = $adminSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $registro;   

    $numeroRegistros = $adminSQL->rowCount();
    

    if ($numeroRegistros >= 1) {

        echo "Bienvenido...";
        header('Location: Vistaadmin.php');
    } else {
        echo "No se encontraron registros";
    }
}
```

Al problema lo tengo en esta línea de código, no me muestra el user del cliente:

`<a class="d-block"><?php $_SESSION['user'] ?></a>`

No se si lo estoy llamando bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no lo estas llamando bien. Tienes dos errores.

El primero es que no estas "usando" el array indicado.

```
<?php

    $sesion = Array (
       "usuario" =>
          Array (
             "id" => 1,
             "nombre" => "Walter",
             "apellido" => "Suarez",
             "user" => "Walter2306",
             "email" => "walter2306@gmail.com",
             "password" => 123456789
          )
    );
```

Usuario es el array al que debes ingresar para buscar el valor que quieres.

```
<?php
    $sesion["usuario"]["user"];
```

El segundo error es que en el Front (HTML) no estas haciendo un echo, al final aunque lo hagas bien, no te mostrará nada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Array</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="d-block"><?php echo $sesion["usuario"]["user"]; ?></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora imagina un array multidimensional muy grande, muchos arrays dentro de uno, que por lo general, los array de sistema son así

```
<?php

    $sesion = Array (
       "usuario" =>
          Array (
             "id" => 1,
             "nombre" => "Walter",
             "apellido" => "Suarez",
             "user" => "Walter2306",
             "email" => "walter2306@gmail.com",
             "password" => 123456789,
             "datos" => array(
                "edad" => 20,
                "otros" => array(
                    "pais" => "España"
                )
             )
          )
    );
```

Igual debes acceder a cada array para coger sus datos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Array</title>
</head>
<body>
    Usuario: <?php echo $sesion["usuario"]["user"]; ?><br>
    Edad: <?php echo $sesion["usuario"]["datos"]["edad"]; ?><br>
    País: <?php echo $sesion["usuario"]["datos"]["otros"]["pais"]; ?><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

```
Usuario: Walter2306
Edad: 20
País: España
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya pude solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos**

De lo que compartes ocurre lo siguiente; conforme al resultado de tu `print_r($_SESSION)` observa que básicamente tienes:

```
Array ( 
   [usuario] => 
      Array ( 
         [id] => 1 
         [nombre] => Walter 
         [apellido] => Suarez 
         [user] => Walter2306 
         [email] => walter2306@gmail.com 
         [password] => 123456789 
      ) 
)
```

Como tal tu índice `["usuario"]` es una *array* que tiene los elementos `id`, `nombre`... `user` y demás. Lo anterior conforme a lo que proporcionaste.

Adicionalmente te comento; no incluiste la línea donde mencionas ocurre el problema.